CRQA optimizeParam errors
I'm trying to run a CRQA in R and as part of that, I'm trying to get the right parameters to use on two time series that have 507 rows of binary data. When I run the optimizeParam bit, I get an error saying Error in ind[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions.
My code currently looks like this
data(crqa)
P1 = ts1$eyes
P2 = ts2$eyes.1

par = list(method = "crqa", metric = "euclidean", maxlag = 20,
           radiusspan = 100, radiussample = 40, normalize = 0,
           rescale = 4, mindiagline = 10, minvertline = 10, tw = 0,
           whiteline = FALSE, recpt = FALSE, side = "both",
           datatype = "categorical", fnnpercent = 100,
           typeami = "mindip", nbins = 50, criterion = "firstBelow",
           threshold = 1, maxEmb = 20, numSamples = 500,
           Rtol = 10, Atol = 2)
results = optimizeParam(P1, P2, par, min.rec = 2, max.rec = 5)
print(unlist(results))

I've tried changing many of the settings, some give the same error (e.g. changing the mindiag and minvertlines to 2, changing the fnnpercent to various things inc NA) and others giving other errors, e.g. changing the maxlag to 30 gives Error in false.nearest(ts1, m = maxEmb, d = del, t = 0, rt = 10, eps = sd(ts1)/10) :
cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb.
I'd like to get parameters for delay, embed and radius for this code sourced from (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crqa/crqa.pdf)
data(crqa)
listener = eyemovement$listener
narrator = eyemovement$narrator
delay = 1; embed = 1; rescale = 0; radius = .1;
normalize = 0; mindiagline = 2; minvertline = 2;
tw = 0; whiteline = FALSE; recpt = FALSE; side = "both"
method = 'crqa'; metric = 'euclidean';
datatype = "categorical"
ans = crqa(narrator, listener, delay, embed, rescale, radius, normalize,
mindiagline, minvertline, tw, whiteline, recpt, side, method,
metric, datatype)

Any advice as to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.
UPDATE: I've tried several more things inc different code and data frames and the error now reads Error in numeric(lag.max + 1) : invalid 'length' argument
current code with demo dataset
library(crqa)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tseriesChaos)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(42)
t <- seq(0,7*pi,,100)
noise <- runif(100, max = 5)

ts1 <- 2*sin(5*t) + noise*5
ts2 <- 3.3*cos(3*t) + noise*2

df <- data.frame(cbind(ts1,ts2))

ggplot(data = df, aes(y = ts1, x = 1:100)) + geom_line(size = 1)
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = ts2, x = 1:100)) + geom_line(size = 1)
ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(y=ts1, x = 1:100), color = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ts2, x = 1:100), color = "red", size = 1) + xlab("Observations") + 
  ylab("Value") + ggtitle("Two Time Series")

mlpar = list(method = "crqa", lgM =  35, radiusspan = 100, radiussample = 100, normalize = 0, rescale = 1, mindiagline = 2, 
             minvertline = 2, tw = 0, whiteline = FALSE, recpt = FALSE, fnnpercent = 10, typeami = "maxlag")

optpar <- optimizeParam(ts1,ts2,mlpar); optpar

traceback() says

3: numeric(lag.max + 1)
2: mutual(ts1, lag.max = maxlag, plot = FALSE)
1: optimizeParam(ts1, ts2, mlpar)


but I don't really know what this means.
